# Using Paperclip to upload images within a json attribute in a model in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, paperclip

I'm currently using Paperclip to manage avatar uploading for users in my Rails app with Amazon S3.
I also have a json attribute in other model (a column) which stores dynamic data. Sometimes this attribute will hold an image and sometimes not.
What I want to achieve is to be able to upload files inside this json column. I thought that just by storing its URL I'd be fine, but unfortunately it's not the case. Since in the model this attribute doesn't have the "has_attached_file", when submitting the form the file doesn't get uploaded. I can't set the attribute to "has_attached_file" because I do other stuff with it and it crushes with Paperclip because it doesn't recognize those methods.

How should I approach this?
**Is there a way to upload files manually?**

what the json looks like:

```
{"title":"my_title","items":
  {"0":{"title":"title_0","type":"text","content":"my_content"},
   "1":{"title":"title_1","type":"image","url":"my_url"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this other column field ? You say you can't store url ? Why ? When you say you want to store an image in this column, do you want to save the image in database as a blob ? Why can't you make this other column a Paperclip attachment in the end ?

Comment: @Maxence I can store the url, the thing is the file doesn't get uploaded to the s3 bucket. I want to upload the file to s3 and the URL get saved in the json. I can't make this column a Paperclip attachment because it's a json which holds lots of other information, besides a file.

Comment: someone may have a solution but why don't you dedicate a proper model to this column. And you store all other information in proper columns. And leave the image column as apaperclip attachment. You can easily serialize your JSON data for each record afterwards.